# Why won't my link take the user anywhere, but if I right click and select "Open in new tab" it will open fine

Tags: html, css

My website is http://christianselig.com, take the About page, in the very bottom footer, if you click "Work" it won't actually go to it, but if I right click and select "Open in new tab" it will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Contact page, your `Javascript` is throwing an error when you click the link. *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"* in `script.js`, line 6.

It seems you're mixing up the `Javascript` that should go on the Contact page with the script that should only be showing up on the Home page. Separate out your scripts so they only appear on their appropriate pages (or do a check to see what page you're on), and the link will work.